# jquery change div size with text toggle

Tags: jquery, dynamic, menu, toggle

I have some headings that toggle text on mouse click. I would like the containing div to grow in size through jquery if the text toggled overflows the current div size...at the moment, the text just overlaps the containing div. :(

text toggle:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".parents-toggle > div").click(function () {
$(".parents-toggle > div..iteminfo-toggle").not($(this).siblings()).slideUp();
$(this).siblings(".iteminfo-toggle").slideToggle();
});
});
```

the html:

```
<div class="container_div">
<div class="parents-toggle">
<div class="itemheadings_toggle">Description</div>
<div class="iteminfo-toggle hidden">
text description
</div>
</div>
<div class="parents-toggle">
<div class="itemheadings_toggle">Description 2</div>
<div class="iteminfo-toggle hidden">
more text
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

div container

```
 .container_div{ width: 400px; height:500px;border: 1px solid #000;float: left;position: relative;}
```

I tried fiddling with something like this, but obviously it is a very failed attempt! Anyone have any ideas what I could do? ><;

```
$('.container_div')({adjustHeight: "dynamic" });
});
```

Comment: It seems like you have your </div> in the wrong spot  see this js fiddle for what i mean. http://jsfiddle.net/b45CX/  I think that is impacting how your script is behaving.

Comment: Oops sorry I didnt space the rest of the divs in the html code above ^^;

Answer (score 0):

You can use word wrap in div.

This Will Solve Your Problem.

div { word-wrap: break-word }